# Open a port in Centos os 8 Running Plesk Firewall

Tags: tcp, centos, port, litespeed

I am trying to open up the port to 7080 for Litespeed Web Console. I have enabled it in the Plesk Interface, I check the IP tables and its there, although twice but netstat returns nothing, blank. Curl says connection refused.

```
IPtables

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7080 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7080 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7080 -j ACCEPT
```

I edited the services vi /etc/services
and found something for 7080

```
empowerid       7080/tcp                # EmpowerID Communication
empowerid       7080/udp                # EmpowerID Communication
```

All help greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it, its actual port 7088